# How to get dollar conversion rate in InApp purchase in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm currently doing InApp purchase in an app, currently I'm following raywenderlich tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial and so far everythings working well. Now the problem is I'm required to do some points calculation based on the product.price from the below function based on dollars. Currently this will work for account based on US market but for other currencies the below log for My point will show a different value. In androids InApp purchase api they also return a microunits apart from price so we can convert into dollar using that microunits, I was wondering if there is any similar thing that is returned in iOS. Is there any workaround for this issue?

```
- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {

    SKPaymentTransaction *transaction=notification.object;
    NSString * productIdentifier = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
    [products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct * product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productIdentifier]) {
            NSLog(@"Current Rate:%@",product.price);
            NSlog(@"My Points:%f" [product.price floatValue]*myPointsFactor);
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: you can use 'pricelocale' property  of SKProduct. to get locale currency.

Answer (score 0):

you can use '`pricelocale`' property  of `SKProduct`. to get locale currency.

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse  *)response {
    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;
    SKProduct *product=myProduct.lastObject;
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [currencyFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];              
    [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];  
   }
```

Comment: I don't think Gamerlegend's asking for the local currency, but asking specifically for the currency in dollars...

Answer (score 0):

check this previous answer for getting the currency

As mentioned in the comments this service was shut down in Nov 2013.

Googles calulator API can do this;

Request:

http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100EUR=?USD
Response:

{lhs: "100 Euros",rhs: "145.67 U.S. dollars",error: "",icc: true}
(More info)

Comment: Yes, but not have much idea but here is the link for you https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=16.6700&from=GYD&to=USD&meta=ei%3DqCe9UpCzCYqvkgX09gE

Comment: No, that api didnt work for me, and finally ended up moving the dollar conversion to backend so from app side we just pass productIdentifier and the transactionId and rest of calculation is done from backend. I didnt look into much detail for google calculator api, the one mentioned in the answer doesnt work, if u just copy paste link on browser u can see there is no response. Just try and look for a valid request. There is a sample project available on gihub which uses yahoofinance api suggested by someone but I havent checked it.This is the link>https://github.com/bjornsallarp/YahooFinance